Time is not displayed in report rdlc c#
I have this SQL query:
string query = "select ScheduleID, DepartureStation, ArrivalStation, Number, WeekDayS, CONVERT(varchar(5), DepartureTime,108), CONVERT(varchar(5), ArrivalTime, 108), TicketPrice from ScheduleView";

using (connection)
{
     connection.Open();

     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     adapter.Fill(ds, "DataSchedule");
}

connection.Close();

I have a view where DepartureTime is of Time type:

And when I want to create report

Value of this field is empty:

How to fix this in the report?

Why is the length 108 characters?  The string is right justified so you are not seeing the Date because of the length.
